# Should I provide new GWT place?

Tags: gwt, google-places

I have a general question for GWT Activity and Places paradigm realization

For example, I have a place "productList" and appropriate view ProductListView. A have a table with some Product entity in each row. I wanna to double click on row and got popup window which allow me to edit Product in doubleclicked row. How to implement it? Should I provide new place "editProduct" for this activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A popup dialog is not a place - users would not expect to see it when they press the back button. So there is no need to create a special EditProduct place.

You can think of "places" as something that users may want to see when they click on Back or Forward buttons, or something they want to bookmark.

Comment: As I understand, place is the state of application which can be reached with special url, for exampl "../editProduct/1". If I wanna to have separate page for editing product, it would definitly new Place.

Comment: It's up to you, but you should look at it from a user's perspective. Do they want to see this "page" when they press the back button? Do they want to bookmark this "page"? If you decide to go with a place for editing products, you may also need to use a token to specify which product is being edited.